# Getting IIS 7 Site properties

Tags: c++, configuration, iis-7, metabase

I have a C++ application that needs to retrieve an IIS 7 site's properties (such as metabase properties similar to those in IIS6 - `Path`, `AppFriendlyName` etc).

With IIS 7, my code does this:

1. Get the `AppHostWritableAdminManager` and commit the path `MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/`.
2. Call `GetAdminSection` with the section name `appSettings`.
3. Then look at the returned collection and look for the property (`Path` for example).

This works in IIS 6 but not on IIS7/7.5.

What changes do I need to make in order to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IIS7 the configuration data is not stored in a "metabase" and also the metabase properties that we're accustomed to in IIS6 aren't the same. IIS7 stores the bulk of its configuration data in the following file:

> `%systemroot%\System32\InetSrv\Config\applicationHost.config`

There are other files, but for the purposes of answering this question, this is the file we're interested in.

The documentation for `applicationHost.config` can be found here:

> [`<system.applicationHost>` - IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost)
>   [configuration Element [IIS 7 Settings Schema]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347524(v=VS.90).aspx)
>   [system.applicationHost Section Group [IIS 7 Settings Schema]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690507(v=VS.90).aspx)

You can find a list of IIS6 metabase -> IIS7 XML configuration mappings here:

> [Converting Metabase Properties to Configuration Settings [IIS 7]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347565(v=VS.90).aspx)

For example in IIS6 the path to a site's `/root` is stored in the `Path` attribute of `IIsWebVirtualDir`. i.e.:

```
<IIsWebServer Location="/LM/W3SVC/67793744" AuthFlags="0" ServerAutoStart="TRUE" 
              ServerBindings="217.69.47.170:80:app2.dev" ServerComment="app2" /> 
<IIsWebVirtualDir Location="/LM/W3SVC/67793744/root" 
    AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript" 
    AppFriendlyName="Default Application" 
    AppIsolated="2" 
    AppRoot="/LM/W3SVC/67793744/Root" 
    AuthFlags="AuthAnonymous | AuthNTLM" 
    DirBrowseFlags="DirBrowseShowDate | DirBrowseShowTime | DirBrowseShowSize |
            DirBrowseShowExtension | DirBrowseShowLongDate | EnableDefaultDoc" 
    Path="D:\websites\ssl-test\www\kerboom" 
    ScriptMaps="...">
```

But in IIS7 it's stored differently:

```
<sites>
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <!-- this is the functional equivalent of the /root app in IIS6 -->
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" 
                              physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
        </application>
    </site>
<sites>
```

However, if your code must work with both IIS6 and IIS7 then you can install the IIS6 Management Compatibility components. This will allow you to access IIS7 site properties using traditional IIS6 metabase API's such as ADSI, System.DirectoryServices etc. The compatibility layer will map these properties to the new IIS7 schema for you.

The first part of this article explains how to install this on Vista/Windows7/Windows 2008:

> [How to install ASP.NET 1.1 with IIS7 on Vista and Windows 2008 - see step #1](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/)

**Update:**

Unfortunately C++ isn't my strong point. However I put together an example in C# using COM Interop to demonstrate using the `AppHostWritableAdminManager`:

```
IAppHostWritableAdminManager wam = new AppHostWritableAdminManager();
IAppHostElement sites = 
   wam.GetAdminSection("system.applicationHost/sites", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST");
IAppHostElementCollection sitesCollection = sites.Collection;

long index = FindSiteIndex(sitesCollection, "MySite");
if(index == -1) throw new Exception("Site not found");

IAppHostElement site = sitesCollection[index];
IAppHostElementCollection bindings = site.ChildElements["bindings"].Collection;

for (int i = 0; i < bindings.Count; i++)
{
  IAppHostElement binding = bindings[i];
  IAppHostProperty protocolProp = binding.GetPropertyByName("protocol");
  IAppHostProperty bindingInformationProp = 
      binding.GetPropertyByName("bindingInformation");

  string protocol = protocolProp.Value;
  string bindingInformation = bindingInformationProp.Value;

  Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", protocol, bindingInformation);

}

static long FindSiteIndex(IAppHostElementCollection sites, string siteName)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count; i++)
  {
    IAppHostElement site = sites[i];
    Debug.WriteLine(site.Name);
    IAppHostProperty prop = site.GetPropertyByName("name");
    if(prop.Value == siteName)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

The code above locates a site named "MySite" in the `<sites>` collection. It then retrieves the site's `<bindings>` collection and print's each bindings `protocol` and `bindingInformation` attributes.

Your should be able to convert this to C++ fairly easily.

To answer the question in your comment -

> For example, the path
>   system.applicationHost/Sites will get
>   me to the list of sites. Is there an
>   absolute way to get to my server
>   bindings like this (for example by
>   doing
>   system.applicationHost/Sites/Default
>   Web Site/Bindings

When using the `AppHostWritableAdminManager` there isn't a shortcut to getting directly to the site you want to inspect/modify or it's properties. In the example above, you'll see that I need to loop through the sites collection to find the site I'm interested in. The reason for this is that `AppHostWritableAdminManager` sees everything as elements and collections of elements. It's a fairly basic API. Even when using the managed `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API you find that whilst there are some nice properties such as `Site.Bindings`, these are thinly disguised wrappers around `AppHostWritableAdminManager`.

In fact if I want to find a site I still have to search the `Sites` collection either in a for loop or by adding some LINQ sugar if I'm using C#3.5 or later:

```
using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Site x = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "MySite");
}
```

`Site`'s base class is `ConfigurationElement` which under the bonnet wraps access to `IAppHostElement`.

Once you're past some basic shortcut wrapper properties much of what we do in managed code to configure IIS (for example IIS FTP) is elements, attributes and collections of elements.

**Update 2:**

Please bear in mind I've never written a line of C++ in my life. There's no cleanup of strings or objects:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ahadmin.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

static IAppHostElement* 
   FindSite(IAppHostElementCollection *pCollection, BSTR bstrSiteName);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);

  IAppHostWritableAdminManager *pMgr = NULL;
  IAppHostElement *pElem = NULL;
  IAppHostElementCollection *pSitesCollection = NULL;
  IAppHostElement *pSite = NULL;
  IAppHostElement *pBindings = NULL;
  IAppHostElement *pBinding = NULL;
  IAppHostElementCollection *pBindingsCollection = NULL;
  IAppHostChildElementCollection *pChildElements = NULL;
  IAppHostProperty *pProtocol = NULL;
  IAppHostProperty *pBindingInformation = NULL;

  BSTR bstrSectionName = SysAllocString( L"system.applicationHost/sites" );
  BSTR bstrConfigCommitPath = SysAllocString( L"MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" );
  BSTR bstrSiteName = SysAllocString( L"MySite" );
  BSTR bstrBindingsConst = SysAllocString( L"bindings" );
  BSTR bstrBindingProtocol = SysAllocString( L"protocol" );
  BSTR bstrBindingInformation = SysAllocString( L"bindingInformation" );

  VARIANT vtPropertyName;
  VARIANT vtIndex;

  HRESULT hr = S_OK;

  hr = CoCreateInstance( __uuidof(AppHostWritableAdminManager), NULL, 
      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IAppHostWritableAdminManager), (void**) &pMgr);

  hr = pMgr->GetAdminSection(bstrSectionName, bstrConfigCommitPath, &pElem);
  hr = pElem->get_Collection(&pSitesCollection);

  pSite = FindSite(pSitesCollection, bstrSiteName);

  hr = pSite->get_ChildElements(&pChildElements);

  vtPropertyName.vt = VT_BSTR;
  vtPropertyName.bstrVal = bstrBindingsConst;

  hr = pChildElements->get_Item(vtPropertyName, &pBindings);
  hr = pBindings->get_Collection(&pBindingsCollection);

  DWORD bindingsCount;
  hr = pBindingsCollection->get_Count(&bindingsCount);

  for(int i = 0; i < bindingsCount; i++)
  {
    vtIndex.lVal = i;
    vtIndex.vt = VT_I4;
    hr = pBindingsCollection->get_Item(vtIndex, &pBinding);

    hr = pBinding->GetPropertyByName(bstrBindingProtocol, &pProtocol);
    hr = pBinding->GetPropertyByName(bstrBindingInformation, &pBindingInformation);

    BSTR bstrProtocol;
    BSTR bstrBindingInformation;

    hr = pProtocol->get_StringValue(&bstrProtocol);
    hr = pBindingInformation->get_StringValue(&bstrBindingInformation);

    _tprintf(_T("Protocol: %s, BindingInfo: %s\n"), bstrProtocol, bstrBindingInformation);
  }

  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}

IAppHostElement* FindSite(IAppHostElementCollection *pCollection, BSTR bstrSiteName)
{
  DWORD count = -1;
  pCollection->get_Count(&count);

  BSTR bstrPropName = SysAllocString( L"name");

  for(DWORD i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    IAppHostElement *site = NULL;
    IAppHostProperty *prop = NULL;
    BSTR bstrPropValue;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    VARIANT vtCount;
    VariantInit(&vtCount);
    vtCount.lVal = i;
    vtCount.vt = VT_I4;

    hr = pCollection->get_Item(vtCount, &site);
    hr = site->GetPropertyByName(bstrPropName, &prop);
    hr = prop->get_StringValue(&bstrPropValue);

    if(wcscmp(bstrPropValue, bstrSiteName) == 0)
    {
      return site;
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Kev, thanks so much for your reply.  Could you please refer me to an explanation of "Admin Section" and commit path? For example, the path system.applicationHost/Sites will get me to the list of sites. Is there an absolute way to get to my server bindings like this (for example by doing system.applicationHost/Sites/Default Web Site/Bindings?

Comment: @ron - please see my updated answer. Hopefully that will clear things up.

Comment: thanks again - I think I am starting to figure this out. Basically, to get to my server bindings, I need to find my website in the system.applicationHost/Sites section, then iterate the collection and find my site. Then, I need to iterate the child elements of my site and look for the bindings. This works great, but is there a way to get directly to the bindings (maybe something like system.applicationHost/Default Web Site/Bindings? Please let me know your thoughts - and thanks so much again

Comment: @ron - you can't go straight to a site and get it's bindings. You have to drill down to find what you want. I've added an example in C++ I cobbled together. Also please note that I've never written a line of C++ in my life so be warned it's a totally dirty hack :).